# Creating Buffers with Barriers using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, buffer, barriers

I have a dataset with about 350 points and another set with road data (polyline). I need to generate individual 500m, 1000m, and 1500m buffers for each of those points; however, whenever a road cuts into one of those buffers, I would like the buffer for that point to end at the road.

To better explain what I am trying to do, essentially I want to imagine that each point is a "light source" with a maximum range of 500m, 1000m, or 1500m, but I want to place barriers to that light (roads) throughout the area covered by those points and use those to generate uneven buffers showing the area touched by "light".

Is there a function that will let you do something like this?

Comment: Run the buffer function, then split the buffers with the road lines.  Then keep only the buffer parts that touch the buffered point.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!